# "Strahlen" vs "Strahler"

Tags: grammar, meaning, german-to-english

I was searching for company names, and reached to a German word 'Strahlen' through Google. As per Google it meant 'rays'. I need a suggestion that, what is the exact meaning of 'Strahlen' and 'Strahler'. Can these be used as noun?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*strahlen* can be either a verb with the meaning of 'to shine', 'to beam',...
or a noun, however, the "S" must be capitalized then: *Strahlen*, which is the plural form to *Strahl*='ray', 'beam'

*Strahler* = an object that emits the beams...

Comment: There also is the figurative [*strahlen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/strahlen#Bedeutung2)

Answer (score 3):

Both of them are nouns. And Google was right with translating `Strahlen` to rays. `Strahler` is the thing which sends out rays, but in a technical sense, like 'projector' or a 'radiator'.